# How to take multiple addresses and validate

Tags: interaction-design, popup

I am working on an application where addresses will be validated before submission.

Steps are:

- take address
- validate
- if address is correct, proceed
- if address is incorrect, user will be prompted with few suggestions, user pick one address and proceed

The problem arises when user adds two addresses and validate. Ref to sample 2 where user wants to add a new address.

User can have two different addresses but the current system validates one address at a time.

I don't want to use popup for adding a new address as the same address component is being used in a popup and opening 2 popups is not viable. Toggling b/w address component may help. What are your views pls.

**Sample 1**
[image]

**Sample 2**[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modals-on-modals is definitely something to avoid. Since you're already designing this to use steps, why not add more steps?

Step 1: User adds official address information

Step 2: User selects validated Official address (if necessary)

Step 3: User adds residential address information (with easy way to populate Official address if same)

Step 4: User selects validated Residential address (if necessary)

Step 5: Confirm what's about to be submitted

You'd change the bottom buttons to "Next" and "Previous" until the last step, which becomes "Submit".

Comment: Thanks. I already have 5 steps :) and want to avoid one more step.